# Exception for .htacess

Tags: redirect, joomla-4.x

I'm using Joomla 4. In the configuration, URL-Rewrite is set to yes.
I think that's what caused this line:

> Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
> RewriteRule. * Index.php [F]

Now I have a problem that cron jobs can no longer be accessed.

The URL `.../index.php?Option=com_acym&ctrl=cron` is redirected to the home page. Is there a possibility to define an exception so that the access from outside works exactly under this URL, although index.php appears in it?

Comment: Welcome Wolf, please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form of a url is index.php?option=com_thingy&task=function.controller

For cron jobs try out the new CLI Console method - there are several examples on the Joomla 4 Tutorials page.

https://docs.joomla.org/JDOC:Joomla_4_Tutorials_Project